# Rails timezone shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way in rails to convert `Mountain Time (US & Canada)` to `EDT`. And are there other names for other worldwide timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anwer your question:

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > now = DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Mountain Time (US & Canada)')
 => Mon, 06 Jan 2014 06:11:53 MST -07:00 
2.0.0p353 :002 > now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 => Mon, 06 Jan 2014 08:11:53 EST -05:00
```

Please notice DST is being handled automatically:

```
2.0.0p353 :009 > now = (DateTime.now+6.months).in_time_zone('Mountain Time (US & Canada)')
 => Sun, 06 Jul 2014 07:14:30 MDT -06:00 
2.0.0p353 :010 > now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') => Sun, 06 Jul 2014 09:14:30 EDT -04:00
```

And of course look at resource linked by @Micheal Moulsdale, you will find there all `TimeZone`s names.

Comment: My goal is to extract `EST`(or whatever will be theze) from `Time` object

Comment: Same method works on `Time`. To check zone simply call `zone` on `Time` object.

Comment: @user2965465 - you should consider changing your question's subject and adding more detail to your question. (This is considering your response to the first answer.)

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be the Active support Time Zone, and then on to the TZInfo gem

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

after you convert the date to the right zone, try date.zone() to get the short zone name.

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(current_user.time_zone)
date.in_time_zone zone
date.zone
```